# Find the period of the related function

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

If F is any function with a period of $6$, determine the period of each related function below:

$y = f(x+1)$

$\displaystyle y = f(\frac{x}{2})$

I know that the basic definition of a period is $f(x) = F(x + P$), but I don't really understand what this question is asking.  Do we substitute $6$ for $y$ and solve?

Answer (score 1):

the first change shifts the whole function by 1 to the left - does this change the period?

The second function rescales the argument in such a way that what took $d$ before now takes $2d$. Does this change the period, and if so, how?

Comment: Ok, I see it now.  So the first one would have the same period, but for the second one, you would divide the period by 1/2 (multiply by two), so the period for the second one would be 12.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, y=f(x+1)just shifts the original one to the left by 1, so the period remains;
  for y=f($x\over2$), it enlarge the function twice in the direction of x-axes so the period is 12.